# I am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))". Unable to find solution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

```
const Header = () => {
const firebaseAuth = getAuth(app);
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const [{user}, dispatch] = useStateValue(); 

const login = async () =>{
    const {
        user: { refreshToken, providerData },
    } = await signInWithPopup(firebaseAuth, provider);
    dispatch({
        type: actionType.SET_USER,
        user: providerData[0],
    });
};
```

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";
export const StateContext = createContext();
export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
  // initial state is already defined as user : null
  // children is basically our component
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);
// Custome Hook
export const useStateValue = () => {
  useContext(StateContext);
};
```

I am using context api to create a data layer at the top of all components. But I am trying that when the user logged in the user information stored in a state and gets updated. But here I am getting an error at `const [{user}, dispatch] = useStateValue();`

Comment: `const [user, dispatch] = useStateValue('');`

Comment: I have tried this but thats not working as well. User is not getting the assigned value

Comment: Show the code of `useStateValue`

Comment: import React, {createContext, useContext, useReducer} from "react";
export const StateContext = createContext();
export const StateProvider = ({reducer, initialState,children}) => (
    // initial state is already defined as user : null
    // children is basically our component
        <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer,initialState)}>
                {children}
        </StateContext.Provider>
)

// Custome Hook
export const useStateValue = () => {
    useContext(StateContext)
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in where useStateValue was defined. I actually mistakenly add curley braces while making a custom hook